# I would like many authors to write a book after przycinku in a row

Tags: sql

I have the following problem. I have a database table:
Publishing and Book, Book_Autor and author.

After joining I get the following result.

My code:

```
SELECT K.ksiazkaID, K.ISBN, K.tytul,SUBSTRING(A.imie,1,LEN(A.imie))+' '+SUBSTRING(A.nazwisko,1,LEN(A.nazwisko)) AS Autorzy,
       W.nazwa_wydawnictwa, K.rok_wydania, KT.nazwa_kategorii, K.ilosc_sztuk, K.cena
FROM Kategorie KT 
JOIN Ksiazki K 
ON KT.kategoriaID = K.kategoriaID 
JOIN Ksiazka_Autor KA
ON K.ksiazkaID = KA.ksiazkaID
JOIN Autorzy A
ON KA.autorID = A.autorID
JOIN Wydawnictwa W 
ON K.wydawnictwoID = W.wydawnictwoID
```

I would like many authors to write a book after przycinku in a row

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Are you trying to concatenate authors of the same book?